# VUE JS Multi Dimensional Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when try to update inner array value with index, it reflects all parent array elements.

```js
this.data = [{files:[{url:''},{url:''}]}, {files:[{url:''},{url:''}]}]; 

this.data[1]['files'][1]['link'] = 'new link';

console.log(this.data);
```

```
[{files:[{url:''},{url:'', link:'new link' }]}, {files:[{url:''},{url:'', link:'new link'}]}];
```

value add/update to all parent items

need to show

```
[{files:[{url:''},{url:''}]}, {files:[{url:''},{url:'', link:'new link'}]}];
```

value add/update to only the parent index  = 1

Comment: Is that really how you're initializing your `files` array, or are you doing something different in your real code?

Comment: this.filesArr = filesInfo; let files = []; files.unshift(...filesInfo.files); files.unshift(...filesInfo.extra_files); this.jobsArr.forEach((job, index) => { this.jobsArr[index]['files'] = files; });       this.jobsArr[1]['files'][1]['url'] = 'newurl';

Comment: And how is `filesInfo.files` initialized? Basically, you're issue seems like you have an array of the same object references in it for each index rather than unique objects. So changing one will change all of them. Either make your original array an array of unique objects (which would involved changing how `filesInfo.files` is populated, or create a new object and assign that to `this.data[1]` instead.

Comment: let data = [{name: 'name',size:'10'}, {name: 'name1',size:'10'}, {name: 'name2',size:'10'}, {name: 'name3',size:'10'}]; let files = [{type:'png', title:'test'}, {type:'jpg', title:'test 1'}];  data.forEach((job, index) => {
    data[index]['files'] = files;
}); console.log(data);     data[1]['files'][1]['url'] = 'ahsfhjds'; console.log(data);     actually this is the issue I faced.

Comment: There you have it - `data[index]['files'] = files` sets each object to the same `files` array reference in memory. Move `let files = [...]` inside your `.forEach()` loop so it creates a new array and objects for each iteration.

Comment: actually I am using VUE JS. I need to append that files into a parent array. then I change the files array from another function. that means  data[1]['files'][1]['url'] = 'ahsfhjds';  this loc is working outside. there we have parent and child array index. get me?

Comment: Does every `data[index]` get the same `files` array, or are you supposed to get the relevant object from `files` based on the current element in the `.forEach`?
Edit: in other words, is there a record that the object in `data` and `files` have in common, that will determine which object from `files` needs to be added to the object in `data`?

Comment: actually files data will change with parent job array. so I append the files array into each job array. then I try to change job[0th element][files][1][url].

Comment: let data = [{name: 'name',size:'10'}, {name: 'name1',size:'10'}, {name: 'name2',size:'10'}, {name: 'name3',size:'10'}]; let files = [{type:'png', title:'test', url:''}, {type:'jpg', title:'test 1', url:''}];  data.forEach((tes, index) => { data[index]['files'] = files; });  data[1]['files'][1]['url'] = '3165487'; console.log(data);    try this code into console. actually I need that url only in the second data element.

Comment: Yeah, then Nick's comment is the way to go.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the later comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated after comments**

From your later comment:

```js
let data = [
  {name: 'name', size: '10'},
  {name: 'name1', size: '10'},
  {name: 'name2', size: '10'},
  {name: 'name3', size: '10'}
];
let files = [{type: 'png', title: 'test'}, {type: 'jpg', title: 'test 1'}];
data.forEach((job, index) => {
  data[index]['files'] = files;
});
console.log(data);
data[1]['files'][1]['url'] = 'ahsfhjds';
console.log(data);
```

Before the `.forEach` you define a `files` array. Then, you add **a reference to this `files` array** as the value of **each** `data[index]['files']`. So, what you are seeing in each of those `data[index]['files']` children, is the original `files array`. Changing a value in one of those references actually changes it in the **main array**, not just in that object.

As [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78052050/vue-js-multi-dimensional-issue/78052219#comment137600965_78052050) also suggested, moving the definition of the `files array` **inside** the loop, recreates it every time, giving each assignment a unique reference.

Better yet, inline it.

```js
data.forEach((job, index) => {
  data[index]['files'] = [{type: 'png', title: 'test'}, {type: 'jpg', title: 'test 1'}];
});
```

Edit 2: Just wanted to add some references where you can read a bit more about this:

- Check out point 4 of the [Array Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#description) on MDN
- [Shallow Copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) can help you understand what's happening here.

Comment: sorry this is not working for me. I am using vue js and data and files send from parent to child componenets as props

Comment: So why not do this in the parent and then only send the updated data to the child component as a prop?